# OpenModelica - Connector generates additional equations than expected

Tags: openmodelica

I'm trying to implement a simple model in OpenModelica, but I got an overnumber of equations caused by the connector.

The tools is composed by three items:

The first is the connector, in which only a flow is defined:

````
```
connector ConnectorMassFlow
flow Real G "Rate [kg/s]";
end ConnectorMassFlow;
```
````

The second is a compressor model, in which 1 connector is defined:

````
```
model ModelCompressor
ConnectorMassFlow MassFlowIn;
equation
end ModelCompressor;
```
````

And then the circuit model, in which the compressor is defined, and another connector as well:

````
```
model ModelConditioner
ConnectorMassFlow MassFlowIn;
ModelCompressor Compressor;
equation
MassFlowIn.G = 1.0;
connect(Compressor.MassFlowIn,MassFlowIn);
end ModelConditioner;
```
````

The problem is that, even if there should be only 2 equations, i.e.:

1. `Compressor.MassFlowIn.G - MassFlowIn.G = 0.0`;
2. `MassFlowIn.G = 1.0`;

OpenModelica is adding another equation, that is:

3. `MassFlowIn.G = 0.0`;

In addition, in the first equation there should be a + between the two terms, and not a minus...

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Connectors in Modelica must be balanced, one potential and one flow (and maybe some stream variables). When connecting them the Kirchhoff laws applies (potentials are kept equal and the flow variables are summed to zero).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I put only G to simplify the question. In the original code, I had one flow (G) and many potentials (pressure, temperature, density, etc). How can I add these potentials while having only 1 flow?

Comment: I guess you can have a look at stream connectors:
https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/stream-connectors.html
or how other people have modeled this type of interfaces:
https://github.com/ThermoSysPro/ThermoSysPro/blob/master/ThermoSysPro/Fluid/Interfaces/Connectors/FluidInlet.mo